# keras "image_dim_ordering" configuration not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, theano

I have been trying to change the keras image dim order from tensorflow order to theano order. I modified `~/.keras/keras.json` file ,the line `"image_dim_ordering": "th"` is not working, but the line  `"backend": "theano"` configuration is working.

```
{
"floatx": "float32",
"epsilon": 1e-07,
"backend": "theano",
"image_dim_ordering": "th"  
}
```

[image]

And when I add `backend.image_dim_ordering('th')` in the beginning of the program,there is a new issue in weights loading. I'm sure the weight is using theano backend, and in "th" order.

```
ValueError: Layer weight shape (3,3,3,64) not compatible with provided weight shape(64,3,3,3)
```

original error without `backend.image_dim_ordering('th')` in the beginning of program:

```
Exception: Layer weight shape (3, 3, 640, 64) not compatible with provided weight shape (64, 3, 3, 3)
```

I am using python 2.7.12 ,the problem occurs both in win7 and Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Comment: Are you using Keras 2.0 API? if yes, then `image_dim_ordering` is replaced by `image_data_format`. See [here](https://keras.io/backend/).

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot.

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: sure,thanks. I'm really new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set_image_dim_ordering` instead of `image_dim_ordering`. The latter only gets the data ordering format but doesn't set it:

```
import keras.backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```